# How do I assign multiple values to a variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know, how to assign multiple values to a variable in vb.
Ive tryed:

```
Public Endings = {".org", ".net", ".com"}
```

But it is not working...
I get errors.

Im making a webbrowser is why I wan't this.
Also ima add other endings ex. .us, .tk, co.cc, ec.

Anyone know how?

Thanks, 
Me

Comment: `Public Endings As String() = {".org", ".net", ".com"}`  turn on Option Strict right away.  it is called an `Array`

Comment: This is off-topic but I would suggest that it's quite bad practice to have a `String` array exposed via a `Public` field.  It's generally bad practice to have anything exposed via a `Public` field unless it's `ReadOnly`.  If you don't intend to change that array then `ReadOnly` is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialise a local variable where you declare it then it's type can be inferred from the value, assuming that Option Infer is On, e.g.

```
Dim myInteger = 100
Dim myString = "Hello World"
Dim myStringArray = {".org", ".net", ".com"}
```

Type inference does not work for member variables though, so you must declare the type explicitly, e.g.

```
Private myInteger As Integer = 100
Private myString As String = "Hello World"
Private myStringArray As String() = {".org", ".net", ".com"}
```

Note also that literal arrays were only introduced in VB 2010 (if memory serves) so, in VB 2008, you'd need this:

```
Private myStringArray As String() = New String() {".org", ".net", ".com"}
```